# Extremal matrix elements in the Unitary Matrix corresponding to a Quantum Circuit

Tags: quantum-algorithms

Quantum Circuits are represented as Unitary Matrices. Given the ability to implement the circuit for Unitary Matrix U, by what algorithmic procedure could one determine the smallest/largest matrix element (taking modulus as the measure of size) in that matrix representation?

I am also interested in the case when one is guaranteed that the matrix has only real numbers, and in that case one can also ask about the "size" as in the largest/smallest (most/least positive) real number.

Comment: Entries in a unitary matrix are generally complex numbers. Do you mean the entry $U_{ij}$ with the smallest modulus?  My intuition is that for a large enough circuit simulating most entries have a modulus of $0$.

Comment: Yes! Edited. Sure, but there are also circuits like QFT where no entry is zero.